# Please help! How to read thumbdrive's "idVendor" & "idProduct" information?

Tags: c#

Currently I'm using WMI to retrieve most of the thumbdrive info... such as "Manufacturer","Serial number" etc. However the most important information i have to and can't read is the "idVendor" & "idProduct".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull this information out of WMI.  Do a search for WMI Code Creator, that provides a fairly easy way to browse around the WMI space, and will even generate code for you to boot.

Comment: I've tried the WMI code creator... but none is close to what i'm looking at... "idVendor" & "idProduct" but thx!

Comment: You have to parse it out of the DeviceID property of CIM_LogicalDevice. I use this query in my code:

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM CIM_LogicalDevice WHERE DeviceID LIKE '%VID_{0}%PID_{1}%'", VendorID, ProductID));

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get a cut and dry breakdown like that. The closest you're going to get is to try the following query and look at the 'caption', 'name', or 'description' columns...

```
Select * from Win32_USBDevice
```

You can try exploding the string by spaces and using the first element in the array as the manufacturer, but thats a hit and miss. Not all devices will store their information in the same column either, so you may have to put some logic into your WMI results to get he format you're looking for.

Disclaimer: I'm on Vista, so I don't know if the WMI provider I just gave is available in earlier versions of Windows.

I'd try using Scriptomatic to query the various WMI providers.

Comment: ok i'll try this out... in my code i'm using Select * from Win32_DiskDrive thx for your info!